# Using CreateSQLQuery Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

When I run these code i got the below errors, Please help me to resolve the problem.

**Code:**

```
public LoanMaturityDate RetrieveChequeDetails(string acctNumber)
{

   // string query = "select  foracid, (SELECT NVL(MAX(lim_exp_date),gam.acct_opn_date) FROM LHT, LHET WHERE LHT.ACID = gam.acid AND LHT.DEL_FLG !='Y'AND LHT.ENTITY_CRE_FLG = 'Y' AND LHT.ACID = LHET.ACID AND LHT.SERIAL_NUM = LHET.SERIAL_NUM AND LHT.APPLICABLE_DATE <= '31-Dec-2012' AND LHET.LIM_INACTIVE_DATE > '31-Dec-2012'AND LHET.LCHG_TIME = ( SELECT MAX(ONE.LCHG_TIME) FROM LHET ONE  WHERE ONE.ACID = LHT.ACID AND   ONE.SERIAL_NUM = LHT.SERIAL_NUM))  from gam where foracid='000333010003520'and schm_type in ('LAA')";

    string query = @"select  foracid, 
                   (SELECT NVL(MAX(lim_exp_date),gam.acct_opn_date)
                    FROM LHT, LHET
                    WHERE LHT.ACID = gam.acid
                    AND LHT.DEL_FLG !='Y'
                    AND LHT.ENTITY_CRE_FLG = 'Y'
                    AND LHT.ACID = LHET.ACID
                    AND LHT.SERIAL_NUM = LHET.SERIAL_NUM
                    AND LHT.APPLICABLE_DATE <= '31-Dec-2012'
                    AND LHET.LIM_INACTIVE_DATE > '31-Dec-2012'
                    AND LHET.LCHG_TIME = ( SELECT MAX(ONE.LCHG_TIME)
                                           FROM LHET ONE
                                           WHERE ONE.ACID = LHT.ACID
                                           AND   ONE.SERIAL_NUM = LHT.SERIAL_NUM)) exp_date
                    from gam where foracid='000333010003520'
                    and schm_type in ('LAA')
                    ";

    ISession session = BuildSession();


    var result = session.CreateSQLQuery(query);//.AddEntity("exp_date", typeof(GAM));//session.CreateSQLQuery(query, "exp_date", typeof(LHT));

    result.AddScalar("foracid", NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String);
    result.AddScalar("exp_date", NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.DateTime);

    var res = result.SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(LoanMaturityDate)));

    return res  as LoanMaturityDate;
}

public class LoanMaturityDate 
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string foracid { get; set; }

    [DataMember]`enter code here`
    public virtual DateTime exp_date { get; set; }
}
```

**Error:**

> ReturnAliases =
>   '((NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl)(result)).ReturnAliases' threw an
>   exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>
> ReturnTypes = '((NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl)(result)).ReturnTypes'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Answer (score 0):

For AliasToBean to work, the returned columns must match exactly the entity's property names and be of the same type.